# Unable to get the name of the input when using getByRole while testing with testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing a component (let's call it MyComponent) which contains a Material Ui TextField component:

```
<TextField
              name="code"
              aria-label="code"
              onKeyPress={keyPressHandler(codeRegExp)}
              value={values.code}
              placeholder={codePlaceholder}
              onChange={handleChange}
              InputProps={{
                classes: {
                  input: classes.code,
                },
              }}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              helperText={
                touchedValues.code && errorValues.code ? errorValues.code : ''
              }
              FormHelperTextProps={{classes: {root: classes.errorMessage}}}
            />
```

I wrote the test for that:

```
test('Checking the initial rendering of the component', () => {
    const initialState = {
      refs: {
        choice: '',
        creationDate: '',
      },
    };
    render(<MyComponent />, {initialState});
    expect(screen.getByRole('textbox', {name: /code/i})).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

The test fails and I got this error:

```
 TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "textbox" and name `/code/i`

    Here are the accessible roles:

      textbox:

      Name "":
      <input
        aria-invalid="false"
        class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input makeStyles-code-9"
        name="code"
        placeholder="ABC_123"
        type="text"
        value=""
      />
```

Should I add the `role=textbox`  for the TextField Component or does the `textbox` role does not works with input elements?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can see from the test output that your `input` element does not have `aria-label`. This causes the accessibility name to be an empty string `""`.

As per [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#textfield) I think you want one of the following

```js
<TextField inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'code' }} />
```

or

```js
<TextField label="code" />
```

---

#### Note

It is a good rule of thumb to try make it work without relying on aria properties first--and then using them if there is no other way. [Read more](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#adding-aria--role-and-other-accessibility-attributes-incorrectly)

---

#### Useful links

- [<TextField />](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#textfield)
- [dont overuse aria](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#adding-aria--role-and-other-accessibility-attributes-incorrectly)